# Using Javascript if else inside MVC .cshtml page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way to use if else statment inside MVC cshtml page

```
 <div class="primary-content">
            if(DetectIE())
            {
            <embed data-bind="attr: { src: data.files()[currentPage()] + '#toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=0' }" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 800px !important;">
            }
            else
            {
            <object data-bind="attr: { data: data.files()[currentPage()] + '#toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=0' }" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px"></object>
            }
        </div>
```

I have a javascript code to detect if the current browser is Internet explorer or not . If it is a IE then `<embed>` tag is used otherwise `<object>` tag is used.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use `@if (DetectIE()) { // embed tag } else { // object tag }` statement. But what is `DetectIE()` do?

Comment: DetectIEit is a javascript method to detect internet explorer

Comment: @if will use c# if else not javascript if else

Comment: Nope, you cannot use JS method with Razor `if` statement. Place the if statement inside the `<script>` tag and append the element with something like `$.append('<embed>...</embed>')`.

Comment: It might be easier to use `Request.Browser` to determine the browser in the controller, and then just pass a `bool` property to your view indicating if its IE or not (as a view model property or a `ViewBag` property)

Comment: Request.Browser sometimes detect IE sometime internet explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `DetectIE()` is a JS function, you can't use it as comparison to Razor `@if` block. You should put it inside `<script>` with `jQuery.append()` to append the proper tag into target element:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    // other stuff

    if (DetectIE())
    {
        $('#targetElement').append("<embed data-bind=\"attr: { src: data.files()[currentPage()] + '#toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=0' }\" type=\"application/pdf\" style=\"width: 100%; height: 800px !important;\">");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#targetElement').append("<object data-bind=\"attr: { data: data.files()[currentPage()] + '#toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=0' }\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"600px\"></object>");
    }
});
</script>
```

Example of the target element:

```
<div id="targetElement" class="primary-content"></div>
```

If you want to check any version of IE from controller side, you can use this:

```
bool isIE = (Request.Browser.Browser == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser == "InternetExplorer");
```

And then pass the value to `ViewBag`:

```
ViewBag.IsIE = isIE;
```

**JS usage example**

```
if (@ViewBag.IsIE)
{
   // render embed tag
}
else
{
   // render object tag
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use javascript function inside razor directly..so bettter use Request .Browser to Get the Browsername

```
@{bool IsIE = false ;
if (Request.Browser.Type.ToUpper().Contains("IE"))
{ 
    IsIE = true;
}

}
@if (IsIE)
{
    // Your Razor here
}
else
{
    //  Your Razor here
}
```

Comment: My method is a javascript method